# In Hive, what is difference between simple and generic UDAF?

Tags: hadoop, hive

There is the documentation page here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy

But there isn't a good distinction between simple and generic UDAF.

If possible, please point to some example.

Comment: I would have a look at [***Programming Hive***](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Hive-Edward-Capriolo/dp/1449319335) by Edward Capriolo, et al.  On pg. 169 there is a section called "UDF versus GenericUDF"

Comment: Just checked the book here. Although the explanation there is for UDFs, it look like it holds for UDAFs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple `UDAF` class `extends UDAF` and have one or multiple static inner class implementing `UDAFEvaluator` (your UDAF logic). At runtime, Hive will use reflection to check witch static inner `UDAFEvaluator` fit the parameters he receive. That will slow the process of the job, but easier to implements.

When using generic UADF, your class extends `AbstractGenericUDAFResolver` and you need to Override the function `getEvaluator(GenericUDAFParameterInfo info)`. That function will give Hive the right Evaluator to use. More complex to implement, but faster at runtime since no reflection is used.